# Fiddler blocking specific https url

Tags: fiddler

I'm using a specific version of Fiddler v 2.3.6.4.

I've noticed that Fiddler cannot load this https url : `https://cyucu.polurl.br-apple.com/.`

What's wrong with this URL ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please upgrade to a modern version of Fiddler; the one you're using is extremely old. Ideally, install Fiddler version 4.5 with .NET Framework 4.5.

As to the error, the server in question is misconfigured such that it doesn't recognize its own name. It sends a TLS `unrecognized_name` alert at a Warning level, which is discouraged by the RFC and not supported by .NET.

To workaround it, you should either configure this connection to use SSL3 or (if you own the server) update the server to recognize its own names in the Apache configuration.

More info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2012/03/28/https-request-hangs-.net-application-connection-on-tls-server-name-indicator-warning.aspx

Comment: Many thanks for that very quick answer. Many thanks for Fiddler and FiddlerCore !